# query using 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select a list of **machines** and kpi's that each one use.

```
KPIs
- id       ('123')

MACHINE
- id       ('567')

KPIDATA
- key      ('k.123.i.567.a.000')
```

KPIDATA row says the **machine 567** uses **kpi 123**. how to select this in one query?

Comment: will the id in KPI and Machine table be a 3 digit id only

Comment: Is this fix format 'k.123.i.567.a.000'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have same format for `Kpidata key` field, i.e. like `k.123.i.567.a.000`

This query can be helpful

```
SELECT 
      k.`id`,
      m.`MACHINE`,
      kd.`key` 
FROM 
      KPIs as k,
      MACHINE as m,
      KPIDATA as kd
WHERE 
      k.`id` = SUBSTR(kd.`key`,LOCATE('.',kd.`key`)+1,3)
AND
      m.`MACHINE` = SUBSTR(kd.`key`,LOCATE('.i.',kd.`key`)+3,3)
```

working demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d814b/17

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT k.id AS key, m.id AS machine
FROM   KPIs k, MACHINE m
WHERE  EXISTS ( 
    SELECT 1 FROM KPIDATA x
    WHERE  x.key LIKE 'k.' + k.id + '.i.' + m.id + '.a.%' );
```